# ExtJS 5: Parent model convert dependency on Child association

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have 2 models... a Parent and a Child... a Parent hasMany Child models. In the Child, I have a field that is created by using its data (in this example, it's just converting and returning 1). In the Parent, I have two conversions going on... one uses its data, and the 2nd one depends on the Child's data. However, when creating the Parent model, it appears the Child association isn't fully baked yet, but when I go to update the Parent model with a new value, the Child association is there.

Basically, what I want to know is, when you see the Total2 console firing, I want Test to be populated. How do I force the associations to be read before using my conversion functions in the parent? And ideally, if there's a change in the Child, the dependent conversion function in Parent will automatically fire... I realize that most likely won't be possible, but it would be an incredible added bonus.

Here's my [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15jr).

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Namespace.model.Parent',
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: onLoadStore
            }
        });
        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'associations',
            store: store,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Primary Key',
                dataIndex: 'PrimaryKey'
            }]
        });
        function onLoadStore(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
            var firstGroups = store.first().getGroupsStore();
            console.log('before', firstGroups.getCount(), firstGroups.isLoaded());
            firstGroups.first().set('GroupName', 'blah');
            store.first().set('blank', 1)
        }
    }
});
```

**Parent**

```
Ext.define('Namespace.model.Parent', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  alias: 'model.parent',
  requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Integer',
    'Ext.data.field.String',
    'Namespace.model.Child'
  ],

  idProperty: "PrimaryKey",
  fields: [{
    type: 'string',
    name: 'PrimaryKey',
    critical: true
  }, {
    type: 'string',
    name: 'Title'
  }, {
      type: 'int',
      name: 'Rating',
      defaultValue: 2
  }, {
      type: 'int',
      name: 'Total',
      depends: ['Rating'],
      convert: function(value, record) {
          console.log('Total', record)
          return record.get('Rating') * 2;
      }
  }, {
      name: 'Total2',
      type: 'int',
      depends: ['groupsMapping', 'blank'],
      // depends on child's Test property
      convert: function(value, record) {
          var groupsMapping = record.get('groupsMapping');
          if (groupsMapping) {
              for (var i = 0; i < groupsMapping.length; i++) {
                  console.log('Total2', groupsMapping[i].GroupName, groupsMapping[i].Test);
              }
          }
          return 0;
      }
  }, {
      name: 'groupsMapping',
      type: 'auto',
      mapping: 'Groups'
  }, {
      name: 'blank',
      type: 'int'
  }],

    hasMany: [{
        model: 'Namespace.model.Child',
        associationKey: 'Groups',
        name: 'getGroupsStore'
    }],

  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data1.json'
  }
});
```

**Child**

```
Ext.define('Namespace.model.Child', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.child',

    fields: [{
        type: 'int',
        name: 'GroupInt',
        critical: true
    }, {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'GroupName'
    }, {
        name: 'Test',
        type: 'int',
        depends: ['GroupName'],
        convert: function() {
            console.log('Test, parent depends on this')
            return 1;
        }
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same problem and took me some time in order to realise that the associations are not available on conversion time

Like in your example, I was sending the child records together with the parent ones (nested) and have 'manually' built a fake store using child model & parent field child data in order to do my math for the conversion / calculation, which did the trick:

```
{
  name: 'validationScore',
  depends: ['childRecords'],
  type: 'number',
  persist: false,
  convertOnSet: true,
  convert: function(val, rec){
    // here we have access only to direct record field, and not the association association !

    // we can use data directly in the calculation
    children = rec.get('childRecords');

    // or build a fake store in order to easily parse them
    children = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      model: 'Namespace.model.ChildModel',
      data: rec.get('childRecords')
    })

    // ... calculate whatever

    return result;
  }
}
```

But now my 'new' challenge is to figure it out a (good) solution to update the converted value upon child records' changes ...

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to qdev, except I listened on the actual association's store.  There's something funky about the constructor though... if I didn't put that timeout in there, then I would get an error with trying to access the first record in the store load... might be a framework bug, or I'm doing something terrible.  The important code is the constructor and calculate method... in the app, I just have a 1 second timeout on changing the child data... you can see the grid's row data change from 3 to 102.  Here's an updated [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18dn):

```
constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var me = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var groupsStore = me.getGroupsStore();
        if (groupsStore) {
            groupsStore.on('update', me.calculateChanges, me);
            groupsStore.on('datachanged', me.calculateChanges, me);
        }
        me.calculateChanges();
    }, 1);
},

calculateChanges: function() {
    console.log('calculating');
    var groupsStore = this.getGroupsStore();
    if (groupsStore) {
        var total2 = 0;
        groupsStore.each(function(group) {
            total2 += group.get('Test');
        });
        this.set('Total2', total2);
    }
},
```